# do new browsers break old HTML/JS/AJAX code?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm considering outsourcing a web application using HTML/JS/JQuery/AJAX technologies. I'm aware the developers spend a lot of time hand tweaking their code to make the result somewhat consistent between the various existing browsers and operating systems out there. My question is, once everything is working fine and the web application is successfully deployed to world, what if a new version of IE, FireFox, etc. is released (which will occur at some point)... are the new browser(s) typically a cause for concern that the once-proven web application may show problems?

More specifically, is it industry practice, after the web application is happily deployed, to keep track of all new releases of the relevant browsers and go through the same hand-tweaking development for each?

If so, is it general practice to always have a budget for this associated cost for maintenance once this technology (HTML/JS/JQuery/AJAX) is committed to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm assuming the web shop your hiring is *good*. If you hire a *shit* web shop (and most of them are shit) then you will need a big budget for someone to come fix all that code two years down the line when it's falling apart.

**Standards compliant code will not break on newer browsers** (as long as browsers comply to standards).

Writing hacked code that uses proprietary browser extensions, deprecated APIs or generally using anything that is not in the W3C standards means that your code breaks whenever browsers vendors feel like dropping support.

Most *competent* web developers write standards compliant code and *warn* you that some feature requests are impossible with the standards and require certain browsers with no guarantee that such feature will continue working in the future.

Generally all browser tweaking done today is making older browsers support your website. Newer browsers should not fail.

Within the industry it's not necessary to hand tweak code for newer browsers versions.

*However* new browsers can and *will* have *bugs*. Dealing with these bugs should be the job of your cross browser compliance library (jQuery and Modernizr). This means that your website may be broken in the first few weeks after browser releases whilst other people are busy fixing the libraries you rely on.

It is *highly* advised to have an automated unit testing suite and to run those tests against betas of newer browsers.

**In general though there should only be problems if your using cutting edge and unstable features. Or if the W3C makes a major u-turn on one of their proposals but then *everyone* has a big problem.**

However I do recommend you have an *"Oh shit"* budget for dealing with *unexpected change in the future*. This does not necessarily have to be for browsers.

Comment: The reason standards compliance is such a big deal is that browsers converge upon the standard. Despite the fact that individual versions vary in the degree to which they succeed in this, your best bet is to align your strategy with browser vendors'. Standards all the way, baby. One word of advice: not all web shops are created equal. There are a lot of ways to execute a given project using the same web tech, and many of those ways are not future-proof. Simply using tech that has well-defined standards is not sufficient.

Comment: @Tom that's a valid point. Back in the 90s standards compliance was a joke. It was all about making sure websites developer for browser X did not run in browser Y by locking people into technologies and APIs. These days browser vendors realise that this generates too much bad karma.

Answer (score 0):

Browser compatibility is definitely a concern of any developer.  In order to determine the relevant course of action, one would need to weigh the pros and cons, and determine if taking the extra time would be worth while to serve a large enough portion of their user base.

Pros:
- Increased compatibility
- Improved usability

Cons:
- Time consuming
- Extra cost (if outsourcing)
- Difficult to test every system

You will find that a lot of newer apps will display a message to the user if their system does not meet that apps' specifications.  Some would say that you are narrowing your user base with this approach, while others would say that it simplifies things.

Either way you choose to proceed, you should always keep future modifications in mind.  After all, you do not want to dump a lot of money into an app that works fine with the majority of today's systems, but may become obsolete in the next 6 months to a year.

Comment: Thanks RobB. Your last sentence is my concern. What options does one have to mitigate the risk associated with this?

Comment: @ggkmath use libraries and frameworks that abstract the browser compliance issue and makes it _someone else's problem_. As long as those libraries and frameworks stay in active development then the problem is mitigated.

Comment: While fortunate for the users, technology is always evolving and can become a hassle for the creator of an app and unfortunately there is no way to avoid having to update your app if you wish to succeed.  There are essentially two options that you would have: a) setup a maintenance clause in the development contract that would entail X amount of hours, every Y months -- may require a retainer fee; b) face the updates when the time comes.  Obviously, they serve the same purpose, but they are just executed differently.

Comment: Typically you can safeguard yourself by ensuring that any development is standards compliant and that the newest, stable technology is being used when possible.

Comment: I guess this should be one big advantage for Flex/Flash compared to HTML/JS/AJAX.

Comment: @ggkmath unless Adobe decides to ruin it for you. Does a game designed for Flash 3 still run on Flash 10? I doubt it does. Exact same issue there. Personally I think W3C is safer for writing future facing code then Adobe.

Comment: From an availability standpoint, Flash will typically have a smaller user base than standard HTML and Javascript.  With this in mind, it ultimately depends on what the application is as far as what technologies can be used.  If you are looking for some sort of animations or "fancy" interactions then you may want to explore a non-Flash route as you can accomplish most of the same items with the use of Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

It's yes to all your questions.

New versions of the browsers may 'break' your pages, especially when it comes to CSS. New versions may have some bugs fixed which previously required hand tweaking. Now, with the bugs fixed, those tweaks are actually causing problems.

Google has a rule to support two last major versions of major browsers. I would choose browsers / versions based on your user base (ie, certain companies may have stopped with Win XP and IE6 on internal machines so all internal websites must support old versions of IE).

If you're thinking seriously about your app than you will have a budget allocated to it.

Comment: Those hand tweaks should not cause problems. If they do then your developers are _no good_

Comment: I wouldn't agree in all the cases. For example, IE6 is not following W3C standards very well, so you need to cater for it. Newer versions are better so your IE6 specific code may not work. You can minimize those issues but IMHO you cannot guarantee in 100% of cases that your IE6 compliant CSS will work in IE9 or IE10.

Comment: but any sensible developer places their IE6 hacks in an if IE6 block. And of course their main CSS is standards compliant so it just works. Unless the entire web sector changes radically in the next 5 years nothing will break.